# Why is my function so slow for specific values?

Tags: python, function, recursion, time, conditional-statements

Beginner programmer here!

So I'm trying to create functions for tetration using a recursive formula. I use that same function `tetrate_F` in finding the nth super root of some big number.
In `sprRt(a, b)`, when `b` gets a tiny bit too high the function seems to slow down by a ton. I find that `2`,`3` and `5` works for pretty much any value of `a`. But when `b` is set to `4` or any other value it just takes so damn long for some reason.

```
def tetrate_F(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return b+1
    else:
        res = a ** tetrate_F(a, b-1)
        return(res)


def sprRt(a, b):
    l_head = []
    lt0 = []

    if b == 1:
        print("Undefined")
    elif b > 1:
        for j in range(0, a+1):
            if tetrate_F(j, b) < a:
                lt0.append(j)
            elif tetrate_F(j, b) > a:
                break
        val0 = lt0[-1]
        lt0.clear()
        l_head.append(val0)
        print(val0)

sprRt(1234567890, 4)
```

Like in `sprRt(1234567890, 2)`, I can use `2`,`3` or even `5` for `b` and get a result almost immediately but not any other number.

Help will be much appreciated thx!

Comment: You're creating enormous numbers when you calculate exponents recursively. This calculation takes a while.

Comment: Thanks but that leaves me unclear as to why only 2,3 and 5 seems to work for every value of a